# Dateformatter iPhone issue

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.departDate);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormat stringFromDate:self.departDate]);
[dateFormat release];
```

So I have this code, which returns this in the console:

```
2011-06-09 00:00:00 +0000
06/08/2011
```

Any ideas why this is happening? As you can see, my self.departDate object returns 2011-06-09 as it's date. When I try to use date formatter to convert, I lose a day WTF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first log corresponds to a GMT date. However when you create an `NSDateFormatter` instance, it will have a default timezone set to the user's timezone which I am guessing is probably somewhere west of Greenwich. If you want the time to remain in GMT, you will have to add this line,

```
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```